# How to convert javascript regex to dart

Tags: javascript, regex, dart

It's first time i am trying regex for a project and i have no idea about it, i did researched but i didn't understand it all how do i convert this '([bcdfgjklmnpqrstvxz]*)' to dart regex, i don't even know what does this regex do i never worked on regex before, if i know what does this regex do i could do it somehow from start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you provided `([bcdfgjklmnpqrstvxz]*)` matches:

- Any sequence of characters that contain only the characters in `bcdfgjklmnpqrstvxz`
- A blank string (the `*` means zero or more)

Here is an example that works if you paste it into [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/):

```
void _parseString(String originalString) {
  RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"([bcdfgjklmnpqrstvxz]*)");
  Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = exp.allMatches(originalString);
  int matchCount = 0;
  for (RegExpMatch match in matches) {
    matchCount++;
    for (int groupCt = 0; groupCt < match.groupCount; groupCt++) {
      print("original string: '${originalString}', match ${matchCount}, group {$groupCt} = ${match.group(groupCt)}");
    }
  }
  if (matchCount == 0) {
    print("original string: '{$originalString}', no matches found.");
  }
}

main() async {
  try {
    _parseString("marshmallow");

  } catch (e, stack) {
    print("Caught $e which was a ${e.runtimeType} error with stack $stack");
  }
}
```

The gist of it is:

- Create a `RegExp` object first with the regular expression you want
- Call `allMatches` on the `RegExp` object with your string
- Iterate through the resulting `RegExpMatch` object

Running the program above will give you this output:

```
original string: 'marshmallow', match 1, group {0} = m
original string: 'marshmallow', match 2, group {0} = 
original string: 'marshmallow', match 3, group {0} = rs
original string: 'marshmallow', match 4, group {0} = 
original string: 'marshmallow', match 5, group {0} = m
original string: 'marshmallow', match 6, group {0} = 
original string: 'marshmallow', match 7, group {0} = ll
original string: 'marshmallow', match 8, group {0} = 
original string: 'marshmallow', match 9, group {0} = 
original string: 'marshmallow', match 10, group {0} =
```

Note that you have all of the blank results due to the * on the end, meaning no characters is a match.  Changing that to a `+` yields these results:

```
original string: 'marshmallow', match 1, group {0} = m
original string: 'marshmallow', match 2, group {0} = rs
original string: 'marshmallow', match 3, group {0} = m
original string: 'marshmallow', match 4, group {0} = ll
```

Which may or may not be helpful depending on what you're doing.  Just reply if you have any questions!

Comment: Its what i need, Thank you very much its worked,

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your expression is just fine, and we can simplify that to:

```
([b-dfgjk-np-tvxz]*)
```

using range metachar `-`.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Dm8SwO/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/Dm8SwO/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---